# Bind kendoui visible to calculated condition in markup?

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

Can i somehow bind a binding like 'visible' in markup to a calculated value in the same way that is possible with knockout.js:

```
<input data-bind="value: someVmProp, visible: (someOtherVmProp === 'custom')" />
```

The syntax I've tried hasn't worked. I want to avoid defining a calculated field in the view model when a simple condition inline would do.

Comment: Can't just put javascript in the data-bind. Is it really that hard to bind to a function in your view-model?

Comment: If "someOtherVmProp" is an observable, then the condition should be "someOtherVmProp() === 'custom'"

Comment: @JFlox ask knockout.js

Comment: Hi TSV i've tried that as well.. doesn't seem to work in kendoui mobile.